# Why does adding independent variables make all independent variables insignificant?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, logit

I am running a logistic regression in Stata to try to determine which independent variables potentially cause a response in a binary dependent variable.  When I run certain independent variables against the dependent variable I get very high significances around $p=.005$. However, when I add all of my variables together into one logistic regression equation all of the significances spike to $.1$ or higher, and many go from $.05$ to $.5$ or higher. It seems that the more variables added, the lower the significance goes, even if the variables are all significant by themselves against the dependent binary variable.

Comment: The answer here is better - more comprehensive, and more to the point - than answers in either of the indicated possible duplicates (though I think one Q. isn't even close to a duplicate, and the other not quite a duplicate).

Comment: @Glen_b: Think it's an FAQ that appears in various guises, e.g. [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/116804/), [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138426/), [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56891/), & [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111745/). But this concise, germane, answer won't be lost if the q. gets closed as a duplicate, will it?

Comment: @Scortchi No, answers are not lost upon closure. They can also be moved over to the duplicate thread via a "merge," which I have done here.